# Imprimir un resultado apartir de un metodo void?

Tags: java, poo, condiciones

tengo estos metodos que son boolean

```
public boolean validateMarks() {
    return (this.qualifyingMarks >= 65 && this.qualifyingMarks <= 100);
}   
public boolean validateCourseId() {
    return (this.courseId >= 1001 && this.courseId <= 1005);
}
```

---

Método `validateMarks()`: en este método pasa si es mayor o igual a 65, si es menor de 65 imprimir "no pasaste"

Método `validateCourseId()`: los cursos son admitidos del 1001 al 1005, si no es el correcto imprimir "curso incorrecto"

Y este es mi código:

```
if(this.validateMarks()) {
    this.courseFee = fee - (fee * discount);
        
    System.out.println("****Course Allocation Details****" + "\n" +
                       "Student Name: " + this.getStudentName() + "\n" + 
                       "Course Id: " + this.getCourseId() + "\n" +
                       "Qualifying Exam Marks: " + this.getQualifyingMarks() + "\n" +
                       "Student's Registration Id: " + this.getRegistrationId() + "\n" +
                       "Total Course Fee: " + this.getCourseFee() + "\n" +
                       "Hostel Required: " + hostel);
} else {
    System.out.println("wrong for marks ");
}
    
if(this.validateCourseId()) {
    this.courseFee = fee - (fee * discount);
        
    System.out.println("****Course Allocation Details****" + "\n" +
                       "Student Name: " + this.getStudentName() + "\n" + 
                       "Course Id: " + this.getCourseId() + "\n" +
                       "Qualifying Exam Marks: " + this.getQualifyingMarks() + "\n" +
                       "Student's Registration Id: " + this.getRegistrationId() + "\n" +
                       "Total Course Fee: " + this.getCourseFee() + "\n" +
                       "Hostel Required: " + hostel);
} else {
    System.out.println("Wroog for course");
}
```

Al momento que pongo en el if(nombre del metodo) siempre me sale el else, apesar de que el resultado sea verdadero.

si la calificacion es mayor a 65, imprime el else tambien, que le hace falta a mi codigo, o que tengo que hacer?

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara. Dices que debe *pasar* si es mayor que `65`, sin embargo tienes esto: `this.qualifyingMarks >= 65 && this.qualifyingMarks >= 100`, lo cual evaluará `true` solamente **cuando sea mayor que 100**. Entonces me pregunto, ¿para qué agregaste esto a tu código: `&& this.qualifyingMarks >= 100`?

Comment: porque "Un estudiante es elegible para obtener la admisión solo si las calificaciones de calificación están en el rango de 65 a 100 (ambos inclusive)"

Comment: Si pero tú pones >=100 eso significa que del 100 al n+ será true. Debería ser: <=100

Comment: Eso no lo explicas en la pregunta. Entonces, así debería funcionar: **`return (qualifyingMarks >= 65 && qualifyingMarks <= 100);`** tienes que poner *menor que 100* no *mayor que 100*.

Comment: es ciertoooo jajajaja apenas lo estoy viendo, deja lo edito, esque ya lo he editado como 100 veces y ya estoy un poquitito desesperado, muchas gracias... algun error que tenga porque no me sale lo otro?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *no me sale lo otro*? ¿Qué sale ahora?

Comment: en si el problema se encuentran en los IF/ELSE del codigo de arriba, porque cuando se ingresa 75, me sale la informacion... pero tambien me sale lo de "informacion incorrecta" cosa que no debe de salir, ya que del this.validateMarks sale si es falso y verdadero, pero no importa si sea true o false, siempre me sale lo de "informacion incorrecta"

Comment: por ejemplo lo corro y me sale wrong for marks 
****Course Allocation Details****
Student Name: Roland
Course Id: 1001
Qualifying Exam Marks: 20.0
Student's Registration Id: 5005
Total Course Fee: 55000.0
Hostel Required: No                                                                                                                         cuando solamente me debe de salir "wrong marks"

Comment: Tienes que unir las 2 condiciones en un solo `if`. Si las pones separadas puede que una se cumpla y la otra no y por eso aunque alguna de las dos condiciones no sea válida, si la otra sí lo es verás la información de todos modos.

Comment: Sí, sería algo como `if (this.validateMarks() && this.validateCourseId()) { /* Correcto */ } if (!this.validateMarks()) { /* Notas incorrectas */ } if (!this.validateCourseId()) { /* Curso incorrecto */ }`

Comment: muchisimas gracias!!! ya me sale lo que tenia que salir correctamente! se los agradezco mucho